# TypeScript literal type parameter doesn't propagate to return

Tags: generics, typescript, type-systems

TypeScript has the convenient property that a literal string can be a type parameter to a generic function. Therefore, you can do

```
let a:HTMLAnchorElement = document.createElement("a");
```

and the compiler knows it's correct (because of the overload `createElement(tagName:"a"):HTMLAnchorElement`).

I had hoped it would be so smart that it also understood the following:

```
function createEl<T extends string>(type:T) {
    let el = document.createElement(type);
    // ...stuff...
    return el;
}
let a:HTMLAnchorElement = createEl("a");
```

But unfortunately, it does not (gives a "not assignable" error). Is there something I'm missing that could make it so, or should I find another approach?

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that [the last signature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L7020) of `createElement` is used:

```
createElement(tagName: string): HTMLElement;
```

This might be the same thing as:

```
function fn(s: "one" | "two") { }
let s = "two";
fn(s); // Error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"one" | "two"'
```

For which there's [an open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9489) for.
Another issue that is opened and might be of interest in this case is [Always use literal types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676).

For now, you can do this:

```
function createEl(type: string) {
    let el = document.createElement(type);
    // ...stuff...
    return el;
}

let d = createEl("div") as HTMLDivElement;
let a = createEl("a") as HTMLAnchorElement;
```

Which isn't as elegant, but it works.